# How to set Row Filter for Dataview to filter rows according to valu of column?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hii,
I am using DataView control to bind a gridview. In dataview data is coming from a table 'cloneUserEntry'. cloneUserEntry table contains a column 'Visibility' whose value is true or false (boolean type). I want to display rows whose visibility is true.
So how to set row filter to filter rows whose column 'visiility' contains only true.
I am using code as following..

```
Boolean var=true ;
gvUserDataReadOnly.DataSource = new DataView(cloneUserEntry, string.Format("Visibility = #{0}#", var),  "FirstName ASC", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

but this is not working. 
can anyone ell me how to do this task..?? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the # characters from the filter statement, i.e., `"Visibility = true"` instead of `"Visibility = #true#"`.  The # are used when filtering using DateTime objects.